# How to get the best performance on leafletjs maps? Should I use 256 px or 64 px tiles, what is the difference?

Tags: leaflet, tiles

I am using leafletjs on a custom map (a game world map). It's an 10240px image and I got it properly setup, but I am noticing a bit of laggy behavior when zooming and navigating. My tiles are properly cut by an automated Photoshop script, and the tile file sizes are also optimized.

Currently my tilesize is the default in leafletjs (256px). But I am wondering if using 64px tiles, would make the performance better or worse? When should 64px tiles be used, and when 256px or 512px tiles should be used?

I couldn't find an particular answer which would satisfy my curiosity on this topic. And I hope someone could clear this up a bit for me. Blessings!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO!

That is a performance optimisation topic that has no fit-for-all answer unfortunately. It is similar to the question of bundling assets (CSS, JS) or even inlining them in the HTML web page.

The base idea is to decrease the time it takes to display meaningful information to the visitor (some refer to as "first paint", although in case of interactive mapping, as you realised this also includes when navigating).

Smaller (but more) files helps avoid loading unnecessary data. For mapping, smaller tiles means less extra data (part of tiles outside viewport), and also in case of Leaflet, faster display of whole tiles (since Leaflet does not display partial tiles, but waits for a tile to be fully loaded to display it).

Bigger (and lesser) files help decrease the number of network requests (usually browsers limit simultaneous requests to 2 per domain by default) and the associated overhead (both in terms of data and time).

When it comes to only map tiles, a rough and simple rule could be: the more detailed and heavy your tiles, the smaller they should be. But as always, experimenting different settings is still necessary.

As for the number of simultaneous requests limit, the "easy" trick, if you can implement it server-side, is to use multiple sub-domains (which can still point to you exact same server files).

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) the trick you mentioned about multiple sub-domains sounds interesting too! Is it something like this? 

My default setup right now: `L.tileLayer('maps/test/{z}/{x}/{y}.png')`

I should place the {z} & {x} & {y} folders onto different subdomains to achieve what you are describing?

Comment: Basically it is like if you cloned your tiles on servers a, b and c so that your Tile Layer URL template can look like "https://{s}.my-doma.in/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png" with "s" being automatically replaced by a, b or c. This is more interesting when your server can detect these subdomains and still serve your original tiles, instead of actually having to clone them.

Comment: You explained this so wellt :) really great answers, this exactly what I was looking for! Thank you once again.